# python - List.remove method not applicable as the function with the map builtin?

Tags: python

## Question

Can `List.remove` not be used as the function to apply in the [map(function, iterable, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) builtin?

```
%%timeit
import random
m = _max = 10000
n = random.randint(1, m)

outer = random.sample(population=range(1, 2*n+1), k=2*n)
inner = random.sample(population=range(1, n+1), k=n)
print(f"outer is {outer}")
print(f"inner is {inner}")

# 622 ms ± 216 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# [o for o in outer if o not in inner]

# 347 ms ± 139 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
for i in inner:
    outer.remove(i)
print(outer)
---

outer is [16, 5, 9, 2, 8, 12, 1, 4, 7, 13, 14, 10, 3, 15, 6, 11]
inner is [4, 1, 5, 8, 6, 7, 2, 3]
[16, 9, 12, 13, 14, 10, 15, 11]
```

I thought it was applicable with the `map` but it returned a list of None. Please advise if it can be applied in some way, or the reason not applicable. Please point out if I made a mistake.

```
#%%timeit
import random
m = _max = 10000
n = random.randint(1, m)

outer = random.sample(population=range(1, 2*n+1), k=2*n)
inner = random.sample(population=range(1, n+1), k=n)
print(f"outer is {outer}")
print(f"inner is {inner}")

print(outer.remove)
print(list(map(outer.remove, inner)))
---

outer is [11, 3, 1, 5, 12, 9, 8, 4, 10, 6, 7, 2]
inner is [1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 2]
<built-in method remove of list object at 0x7f470b6fbd00>
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: It works as expected. `remove` affects the initial list but returns nothing (`None`). Print `outer` again and it should be shorter.

Comment: @Guimoute, please add that in the answer section. This is a straight forward answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. `remove` affects the initial list but returns nothing (`None`). Print `outer` again and it should be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works as desired. The remove function affects the initial list but its return value is None. Simply Print outer again and it will be shorter!

Comment: "Can I copy your ~~homework~~ comment?" "Sure but change it a little."

Comment: @Guimonte My post was on January 25th, yours on January 26th - so who copied whose "homework" ?

Comment: The comment that I turned in an answer was written 20 minutes before your answer.