# Why map(outer.remove, inner) does not work to remove inner from outer?

Tags: python

Please help understand why applying the `outer.remove` method on `inner` doe not remove the inner list elements from the outer list.

My sincere apology for having asked [python - List.remove method not applicable as the function with the map builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893890/) wrongly, hence opening a new question.

I thought `List.remove` would be a function associated to the `outer` list object, hence applying it to `inner` would update the `outer` list via `map`. However, apparently the `<built-in method remove of list object at 0x7fbd8411a840>` is not updating the `outer` list it is associated to.

Please help understand if this is work as designed and what is happening under the hood in the Python interpreter. If there is a way to apply `<list object>.remove` via the map builtin.

```
import copy

n = 10
outer = list(range(1, 2*n+1))
inner = list(range(1, n+1))

print(f"outer is {outer}")
print(f"inner is {inner}\n")

_outer = copy.deepcopy(outer)
for i in inner:
    _outer.remove(i)
print(f"for loop application of outer.remove(inner_element) is \n{_outer}\n")

print(f"outer.remove is {outer.remove}")
map(outer.remove, inner)
print(f"map application of outer.remove is \n{outer}")
```

Result

```
outer is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
inner is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for loop application of outer.remove(inner_element) is 
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

outer.remove is <built-in method remove of list object at 0x7fbd8411a840>
map application of outer.remove is 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, `map()` returns a generator - nothing happens immediately, you have to iterate the generator to get it to actually apply the specified function.  Writing it as `list(map(...))` would be one way to do this (of course, this would generate a completely useless list of Nones in the process).

Comment: `map(outer.remove, inner)` creates a `map` object, an *iterator*. You would have to iterate over it. **But you shouldn't use map like this**. `map` is a functional programming construct, don't use it for side-effects

Comment: @jasonharper to be pedantic, `map` does not return a generator, it returns a `map` object, which is an *iterator* but not a generator

Comment: And aside from a bad mixture of imperative/functional style, `.remove` in a loop is unnecessarily inefficient, whether it be `map` or a for-loop

Answer (score 2):

python has several elements of functional languages like lazy evaluation, which postpones execution until the computation result is needed. When calling

```
map(outer.remove, inner)
```

you are creating a mapping object, which will not apply dirty method `remove` to inner list until the computation "result" is actually demanded. Like e.g. when you put it on the list (which is immediately lost from the scope)

```
list(map(outer.remove, inner))
```

imho it`s generally a bad practice to mix functional programming and functions with side effects